# How to understand percents in perf?

Tags: c++, perf

Consider the following application.

```cpp
#include <cmath>

void foo()
{
    double x = 42.0;
    for ( unsigned long i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
        x = std::sin( x );
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

I use the following commands.

```bash
g++ main.cpp
perf record ./a.out
perf report
```

And I see.

```
Samples: 518  of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 410229343
Overhead  Command  Shared Object      Symbol
  84,28%  a.out    libm.so.6          [.] __subtf3
  12,59%  a.out    a.out              [.] foo
   2,47%  a.out    a.out              [.] _init
   0,47%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] may_open
   0,17%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] memcg_slab_post_alloc_hook
   0,01%  perf-ex  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] mutex_unlock
   0,01%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __intel_pmu_enable_all.constprop.0
   0,00%  perf-ex  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr
   0,00%  a.out    [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] native_write_msr
```

How to understand 12,59% for `foo`?

How to tell `perf report` to show full percent of time spent in a function? I want to see something like - `foo` 99%, `__subtf3` 90%.

Answer (score 2):

This is a half of an answer. I will answer myself on the second question.

Use the following command to see percents as you wish.

```
perf record -e cpu-cycles --call-graph dwarf,4096 -F 250 ./a.out
perf report
```

And the result will look like.

```
+  100,00%     0,00%  a.out    a.out              [.] _start
+  100,00%     0,00%  a.out    libc.so.6          [.] __libc_start_main_impl (inlined)
+  100,00%     0,00%  a.out    libc.so.6          [.] __libc_start_call_main (inlined)
+  100,00%     0,00%  a.out    a.out              [.] main
+  100,00%    16,27%  a.out    a.out              [.] foo
+   83,73%     0,00%  a.out    libm.so.6          [.] __sin_fma (inlined)
+   83,73%    83,73%  a.out    libm.so.6          [.] __subtf3
+   62,87%     0,00%  a.out    libm.so.6          [.] do_sin (inlined)
+    5,85%     0,00%  a.out    libm.so.6          [.] libc_feholdsetround_sse_ctx (inlined)                  
...
```